# How to escape parent attribute in BeautifulSoup ISO tag actually named <parent>?

Tags: python, xml, dom, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

OK, this is kind of funny.  Here is the XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    </build>
```

I want to use the simple `BeautifulSoup` hierarchical notation to get to the node actually named `<parent>` but `parent` is actually a reserved attribute label in this API.

```
with open(pom) as pomHandle:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pomHandle)

#this returns the proper build node
buildNode = soup.project.build
#this does not return the proper parent node but the XML parent of the project node
#(which is the whole doc) because 'parent' is reserved
parentNode = soup.project.parent
```

How do I override this limitation?

Comment: Deleted my answer, seems like i missed something. alecxe's answer should suffice, i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find()` instead:

```
soup.project.find('parent')
```

Essentially this is the same thing since `BeautifulSoup` uses `find` under-the-hood in `__getattr__()` method of a `Tag` class.

Hope that helps.